# How to retrieve Android bug reports after encountering error "No apps can perform this action"

Tags: android, android-debug, android-debugging

I strictly followed [the official instructions to get an Android bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report) but got the following error ("No apps can perform this action"):

[image]

Could anyone offer a tip on how to get the bug report in this case? It is an Android 12 device.